# Round corner tab in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, tabs, rounded-corners

Round corner tab in jQuery Mobile

I have come across navbar in jquery mobile which can be used as tabs.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

However my requirement is to use round cornered tabs like the we have in general jQuery.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

I need round corner tabs in jQuery mobile. Is there any way to use css such a way that the navbar can be changed to round cornered tabs ?

Also my requirement is to have the selected tabs connected to its corresponding div as it is in the above jquery example to give a look and feel of real tabs instead of mere buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to your CSS should do it:

```
.ui-btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it works , the top part of the button becomes round , however I was trying get the selected tabs connected to its corresponding div as it is in the above jquery example to give a look and feel of real tabs instead of mere buttons.(the unselected tab should look disconnected ). Will changing the color of the selected div or a small bar below the tab matching the tab color do  ?